# Shorthand way to write Conditional in Javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I usually run into writing conditionals like this and I'm wondering if there a short hand way to write something similar below without calling a function

```
const currentValue = this.props.book.location.areaValueInDollars ? this.props.book.location.areaValueInDollars : 0;
```

Comment: `const currentValue = this.props.book.location.areaValueInDollars ?? 0;` If `this.props.book.location.areaValueInDollars` is `undefined` or `null` then `currentValue` will get `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nullish coalescing operator:

```
this.props.book.location.areaValueInDollars || 0
```

More on the subject here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 2):

You can use short-circuiting and the [Logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR).

```js
const currentValue = window['a'] || 0; 

console.log(currentValue);
```

If the variable exists, then the first operand will return `true`, causing it to "short circuit" and be returned. The second operand is only evaluated if the first is `false`, since the expression is evaluated from left to right.

---

Using the Logical OR operator has a caveat though. If the variable is `0`, `null`, `undefined`... (for full list, see [Falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)), it will return false.

To solve this, we can use the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), which will only return the right-hand side operand if the left operand is `null` or `undefined`. Like so:

```js
const currentValue = window['a'] ?? 0; 

console.log(currentValue);
```